# URI not supported by CordovaResourceApi

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer

I am trying to to download a file and save it (overwrite it if is the case) in my **www** folder of the app.

Can you please guide me to some code example?

This is my code i tried:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);

var store2;

var assetURL = "http://www.mydomain.eu/path/untitled.png";

var fileName = "bg.png";

function init() {
    try {

       store2 = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/';              

    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err.message);
    }
}

function downloadAsset2() {

    try {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        alert("aa->" + store2 + fileName)
        fileTransfer.download(assetURL, store2 + fileName,
            function (entry) {

                location.reload();
                alert("->" + store2 + fileName)
            },
            function (err) {                
                alert(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
            });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err.message);
    }
}
```

and this is the error i get

```
URI not supported by CordovaResourceApi: file:///android_asset/www/bg.png
```

Comment: I guess the assets are read only.

Comment: hmm.. it may be because this code works pefect if i use cordova.file.dataDirectory path instead, but i am not sure ..

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't download anything in `www` folder. That's not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if OP has solved this problem already or not, unfortunately the "applicationDirectory" is read-only.

Here is some further info that I found from the cordovaFile plugin webpage:

(Reference: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

Not sure how to insert the big table here so I made it as a snippet, simply run it and you will see the table or you can directly go to the gitHub page for further information

```html
<h3><a id="user-content-ios-file-system-layout" class="anchor" href="#ios-file-system-layout" aria-hidden="true"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-link" height="16" role="img" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16"><path d="M4 9h1v1h-1c-1.5 0-3-1.69-3-3.5s1.55-3.5 3-3.5h4c1.45 0 3 1.69 3 3.5 0 1.41-0.91 2.72-2 3.25v-1.16c0.58-0.45 1-1.27 1-2.09 0-1.28-1.02-2.5-2-2.5H4c-0.98 0-2 1.22-2 2.5s1 2.5 2 2.5z m9-3h-1v1h1c1 0 2 1.22 2 2.5s-1.02 2.5-2 2.5H9c-0.98 0-2-1.22-2-2.5 0-0.83 0.42-1.64 1-2.09v-1.16c-1.09 0.53-2 1.84-2 3.25 0 1.81 1.55 3.5 3 3.5h4c1.45 0 3-1.69 3-3.5s-1.5-3.5-3-3.5z"></path></svg></a>iOS File System Layout</h3>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="left">Device Path</th>
      <th align="left"><code>cordova.file.*</code>
      </th>
      <th align="left"><code>iosExtraFileSystems</code>
      </th>
      <th align="center">r/w?</th>
      <th align="center">persistent?</th>
      <th align="center">OS clears</th>
      <th align="center">sync</th>
      <th align="center">private</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><code>/var/mobile/Applications/&lt;UUID&gt;/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">applicationStorageDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">-</td>
      <td align="center">r</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>appname.app/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">applicationDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">bundle</td>
      <td align="center">r</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>www/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">-</td>
      <td align="left">-</td>
      <td align="center">r</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>Documents/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">documentsDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">documents</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>NoCloud/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">-</td>
      <td align="left">documents-nosync</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>Library</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">-</td>
      <td align="left">library</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">Yes?</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>NoCloud/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">dataDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">library-nosync</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>Cloud/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">syncedDataDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">-</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>Caches/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">cacheDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">cache</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes*</td>
      <td align="center">Yes***</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>tmp/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">tempDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">-</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">No**</td>
      <td align="center">Yes***</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>* Files persist across app restarts and upgrades, but this directory can be cleared whenever the OS desires. Your app should be able to recreate any content that might be deleted.</p>

<p>** Files may persist across app restarts, but do not rely on this behavior. Files are not guaranteed to persist across updates. Your app should remove files from this directory when it is applicable, as the OS does not guarantee when (or even if) these
  files are removed.</p>

<p>*** The OS may clear the contents of this directory whenever it feels it is necessary, but do not rely on this. You should clear this directory as appropriate for your application.</p>

<h3><a id="user-content-android-file-system-layout" class="anchor" href="#android-file-system-layout" aria-hidden="true"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-link" height="16" role="img" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16"><path d="M4 9h1v1h-1c-1.5 0-3-1.69-3-3.5s1.55-3.5 3-3.5h4c1.45 0 3 1.69 3 3.5 0 1.41-0.91 2.72-2 3.25v-1.16c0.58-0.45 1-1.27 1-2.09 0-1.28-1.02-2.5-2-2.5H4c-0.98 0-2 1.22-2 2.5s1 2.5 2 2.5z m9-3h-1v1h1c1 0 2 1.22 2 2.5s-1.02 2.5-2 2.5H9c-0.98 0-2-1.22-2-2.5 0-0.83 0.42-1.64 1-2.09v-1.16c-1.09 0.53-2 1.84-2 3.25 0 1.81 1.55 3.5 3 3.5h4c1.45 0 3-1.69 3-3.5s-1.5-3.5-3-3.5z"></path></svg></a>Android File System Layout</h3>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="left">Device Path</th>
      <th align="left"><code>cordova.file.*</code>
      </th>
      <th align="left"><code>AndroidExtraFileSystems</code>
      </th>
      <th align="center">r/w?</th>
      <th align="center">persistent?</th>
      <th align="center">OS clears</th>
      <th align="center">private</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><code>file:///android_asset/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">applicationDirectory</td>
      <td align="left"></td>
      <td align="center">r</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><code>/data/data/&lt;app-id&gt;/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">applicationStorageDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">-</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">N/A</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>cache</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">cacheDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">cache</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">Yes*</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>files</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">dataDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">files</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>Documents</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left"></td>
      <td align="left">documents</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><code>&lt;sdcard&gt;/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">externalRootDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">sdcard</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>Android/data/&lt;app-id&gt;/</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">externalApplicationStorageDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">-</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>cache</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">externalCacheDirectry</td>
      <td align="left">cache-external</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No**</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"> <code>files</code>
      </td>
      <td align="left">externalDataDirectory</td>
      <td align="left">files-external</td>
      <td align="center">r/w</td>
      <td align="center">Yes</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
      <td align="center">No</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>* The OS may periodically clear this directory, but do not rely on this behavior. Clear the contents of this directory as appropriate for your application. Should a user purge the cache manually, the contents of this directory are removed.</p>

<p>** The OS does not clear this directory automatically; you are responsible for managing the contents yourself. Should the user purge the cache manually, the contents of the directory are removed.</p>

<p><strong>Note</strong>: If external storage can't be mounted, the <code>cordova.file.external*</code>
  properties are <code>null</code>.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `store2  = cordova.file.dataDirectory ;`
this one refers to `files` in android and it's R/W (read and write are permitted  ).

> reference : [Android File System Layout](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#android-file-system-layout)